# MongoDB PHP SSL Connection libmongoc SSL

Tags: php, mongodb, ssl

I want to connect into my mongodb with authentication but it gives me this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPvnB.png

When I try to force use of SSL Option in my code. It gives me this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSrTC.png

This is my phpinfo. I believe this option should be enabled. I already tried my articles about this but no use
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdYgt.png

Comment: I'm pretty certain that all of those errors are actually in "text", so please don't post pictures of them. Select the "text" and include the error "text" in the question itself. Better yet, search for existing answers on the subject that probably reference the same errors. And then include your steps taken in installation so far